# Faster 3D Matrix Operation - Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix

I am working with 3D matrix in Python, for example, given matrix like this with size of 2x3x4:

```
[[[1 2 1 4]
  [3 2 1 1]
  [4 3 1 4]]

 [[2 1 3 3]
  [1 4 2 1]
  [3 2 3 3]]]
```

I have task to find the value of entropy in each row in each dimension matrix. For example, in row 1 of dimension 1 of the matrix above `[1,2,1,4]`, the normalized value (as such the total sum is 1) is `[0.125, 0.25, 0.125, 0.5]` and the value of entropy is calculated by the formula `-sum(i*log(i))` where i is the normalized value. The resulting matrix is a 2x3 matrix where in each dimension there are 3 values of entropy (because there are 3 rows).

Here is the working example of my code using random matrix each time:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(low=1,high=5,size=(2,3,4)) #how if size is (200,50,1000)
entropy_matrix=np.zeros((matrix.shape[0],matrix.shape[1]))
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    normalized = np.array([float(k)/np.sum(j) for j in matrix[i] for k in j]).reshape(matrix.shape[1],matrix.shape[2])
    entropy_matrix[i] = np.array([entropy(m) for m in normalized])
```

My question is how do I scale-up this program to work with very large 3D matrix (for example with size of 200x50x1000) ?

I am using Python in Windows 10 (with Anaconda distribution). 
Using 3D matrix size of 200x50x1000, I got running time of 290 s on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster if you use the built-in functions of numpy (instead of reimplementing them yourself):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy

np.apply_along_axis(func1d=entropy, axis=2, arr=matrix)
```

Comment: It is always faster to use functions of numpy because most of its code is written in C, which is about 20-100 times faster than Python